# Why it not working? following angularjs Example

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Here i created some Example.. In this Example 1 I put directly
//{{arr.Description}}
like this its working but via directive its not working what misstake i did 
can please explain me?
Thanks friends

```js
var app = angular.module('components', []);
   app.directive('subpane', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { 
          array: '@' 
       },
      template:'<li ng-repeat="arr in array">{{arr.Description}}</li>',
      
      link: function(scope) {

      }
      
    };
  })
  app.controller('tabController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
           $scope.array =[{
                          "title": 0,
                          "Description": "Select your option"
                        },
                        {
                          "title": 1,
                          "Description": "Male"
                        },
                        {
                          "title": 2,
                          "Description": "Female"
                        },
                        {
                          "title": 3,
                          "Description": "Unknown"
                        }];
  }])
```

```html
 <script data-require="angular.js@~1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="components" ng-controller="tabController">

<span>Example 1 Working fine</span>
<li ng-repeat="arr in array">{{arr.Description}}</li>

<span>Example 2 Not Working.. Here also same thing only i did via directive.. why this is not working?</span>

 <subpane array={{array}}></subpane>
 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use '=' for the scope param and remove '{{}}' in the markup.

```js
var app = angular.module('components', []);
   app.directive('subpane', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: { 
          array: '=' 
       },
      template:'<li ng-repeat="arr in array">{{arr.Description}}</li>',
      
      link: function(scope) {

      }
      
    };
  })
  app.controller('tabController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
           $scope.array =[{
                          "title": 0,
                          "Description": "Select your option"
                        },
                        {
                          "title": 1,
                          "Description": "Male"
                        },
                        {
                          "title": 2,
                          "Description": "Female"
                        },
                        {
                          "title": 3,
                          "Description": "Unknown"
                        }];
  }])
```

```html
 <script data-require="angular.js@~1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="components" ng-controller="tabController">

<span>Example 1 Working fine</span>
<li ng-repeat="arr in array">{{arr.Description}}</li>

<span>Example 2 Not Working.. Here also same thing only i did via directive.. why this is not working?</span>

 <subpane array=array></subpane>
 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "plain: true" in the directive if you don't use templateUrl

```
  app.directive('subpane', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: { 
        array: '=' // = not @, = is for object/array ; = is for text/number.
     },
    template:'<li ng-repeat="arr in array">{{arr.Description}}</li>',
    plain: true,
    link: function(scope) {

    }

  };
})
```

In the html  dont put {{ }} in the parameter array

```
<subpane array="array"></subpane>
```

Answer (score -1):

camden_kid has posted an acceptable answer but not probably the best one. In your template:

```
<subpane array={{array}}></subpane>
```

Must have the quotes:

```
<subpane array="{{array}}"></subpane>
```

Please also note that camden_kid suggested to change

```
scope: { 
    array: '@' 
}
```

To

```
scope: { 
    array: '=' 
}
```

This is what is needed for **double binding** and it is only necessary if you have to *edit* in any way the original value (in the parent scope) from within the directive's isolated scope.

You probably should read more carefully the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: when you use `=` for binding you should NOT use `{{array}}` but `array` instead!